# Why won't this pass any of the tests for receiving the largest array element as a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, properties

Question:

Given an object and a key, write a function that returns the largest element in the array located at the given key.

Notes:

- If the array is empty, it should return undefined.
- If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return undefined.
- If there is no property at the key, it should return undefined.

code:

```
Test obj: var obj = { key: [1, 2, 4]};

function getLargestElementAtProperty(obj, key) {
var prop = obj[key]
if (!prop || prop.length === 0 || !Array.isArray(prop)){ 
    return undefined
   }
var max = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < prop.length; i++){
     if (prop[i] > max) max = prop[i]
   }
return max
}
getLargestElementAtProperty(obj, 'key'); // 4
```

Question: My code works for every requirement in the notes and returns the maximum value when I run it through an object.  It returns undefined for said requirements in the notes, but it doesn't pass any tests in the repl.  The tests are the 3 notes and then returning the maximum value and it fails all of them.  Why is this? What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Please write code which don't works.

Comment: Can you show us the test that fails? The question says "largest *element*"; does it say anything on how to handle non-number values?

Comment: Doesn't pass tests in *what* repl…?

Comment: https://repl.it/student/submissions/100216 here's the code in repl if you can open and run it. I get the return value on my screen but the test still fails. I didnt think about it handling non-numeric values, the test property is all numbers.  not quite sure how I would handle that

Comment: You should start with `var max = prop[0]`, not `0`. Otherwise it'll fail for arrays that contain only negative numbers, and possibly on arrays that don't contain any numbers as well.

Comment: This is the code that doesn't work.  @G

Comment: No, we cannot access that (at least I can't). Which leaves us with code which works as far as anyone can tell with an unclear description of what's wrong with it. Voting to close.

Comment: prop[0] doesn't help it pass the notes requirements

Comment: Please run it in repl if you can from my link

Comment: @deceze can you run my link to see what I'm saying?

Comment: Again, no, **I cannot** access that link. → 404

Comment: Oh thats what you meant.  Does this appear correct though?